# UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path [ios/ Mac os Mojava / Unity 19.2.0] failing to build project

Tags: macos, firebase, unity-game-engine, build, vuforia

I was able to build the exact same project on the exact same Macbook pro last week but now I no longer am and I don't understand why.

Now when I first open the project (I am primarily working on a windows computer for the android version of this project, using the mac just to make builds) it says:

An error occurred while resolving packages:

```
 One or more packages could not be added to the local file system:
    com.unity.collab-proxy: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink '/Users/dondoo/Desktop/Grove_Anniversary/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.collab-proxy@1.2.16/CHANGELOG.md'
    com.unity.ext.nunit: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink '/Users/dondoo/Desktop/Grove_Anniversary/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ext.nunit@1.0.0/.gitlab-ci.yml'
    com.unity.ide.rider: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink '/Users/dondoo/Desktop/Grove_Anniversary/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ide.rider@1.0.8/.editorconfig'
    com.unity.ide.vscode: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink '/Users/dondoo/Desktop/Grove_Anniversary/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ide.vscode@1.0.7/CHANGELOG.md.meta'
    com.unity.test-framework: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink '/Users/dondoo/Desktop/Grove_Anniversary/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.test-framework@1.0.13/CHANGELOG.md'
    com.unity.textmeshpro: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink '/Users/dondoo/Desktop/Grove_Anniversary/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.textmeshpro@2.0.1/.gitlab-ci.yml'
```

It crashes after that then when I reopen it there is no issue but when i try build then I get this error:

```
UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "/Users/dondoo/Desktop/Grove_Anniversary/Temp/StagingArea/Data/Managed/Vuforia.UnityExtensions.dll" is denied.
System.IO.File.Delete (System.String path) (at <a8ed250850854b439cedc18931a314fe>:0)
UnityEditorInternal.AssemblyStripper.RunAssemblyStripper (System.Collections.IEnumerable assemblies, System.String managedAssemblyFolderPath, System.String[] assembliesToStrip, System.String[] searchDirs, System.String monoLinkerPath, UnityEditorInternal.IIl2CppPlatformProvider platformProvider, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry rcr, UnityEditor.ManagedStrippingLevel managedStrippingLevel) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/AssemblyStripper.cs:412)
UnityEditorInternal.AssemblyStripper.StripAssemblies (System.String managedAssemblyFolderPath, UnityEditorInternal.IIl2CppPlatformProvider platformProvider, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry rcr, UnityEditor.ManagedStrippingLevel managedStrippingLevel) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/AssemblyStripper.cs:246)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.Run () (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:326)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPUtils.RunIl2Cpp (System.String tempFolder, System.String stagingAreaData, UnityEditorInternal.IIl2CppPlatformProvider platformProvider, System.Action`1[T] modifyOutputBeforeCompile, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry runtimeClassRegistry) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:63)
UnityEditor.iOS.PostProcessiPhonePlayer.CrossCompileManagedDlls (UnityEditor.iOS.PostProcessiPhonePlayer+BuildSettings bs, UnityEditor.iOS.PostProcessiPhonePlayer+ProjectPaths paths, UnityEditor.AssemblyReferenceChecker checker, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport buildReport) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/iPhonePlayer/Extensions/Common/BuildPostProcessor.cs:813)
UnityEditor.iOS.PostProcessiPhonePlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.iOS.PostProcessiPhonePlayer+BuildSettings bs, UnityEditor.iOS.PostProcessiPhonePlayer+ProjectPaths paths, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport buildReport) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/iPhonePlayer/Extensions/Common/BuildPostProcessor.cs:635)
UnityEditor.iOS.PostProcessiPhonePlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.iOS.PostProcessorSettings postProcessorSettings, UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/iPhonePlayer/Extensions/Common/BuildPostProcessor.cs:582)
UnityEditor.iOS.iOSBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/iPhonePlayer/Extensions/Common/ExtensionModule.cs:45)
Rethrow as BuildFailedException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
UnityEditor.iOS.iOSBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/PlatformDependent/iPhonePlayer/Extensions/Common/ExtensionModule.cs:49)
UnityEditor.Modules.DefaultBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Modules/DefaultBuildPostprocessor.cs:27)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:281)
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallGlobalEventHandler()
```

I have tried reimporting everything. 
I have tried different versions of unity.
I can't build on a windows pc, because firebase doesn't allow ios builds from a computer that's not using MacOsX.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that it's safe to delete the Library directory if Unity is running. I actually add `Library`, `Temp`, `obj`, and `Logs` to my `.gitignore` file when sharing a project between machines.

I do notice `/Users/dondoo` and `/Users/builduser` in your logs. You also want to make sure that whichever user account needs access to your Unity project can get it (ie: if you're running Unity as `builduser` but the folder is only accessible by `dondoo`, you'll have a bad time). Since you appear to have an issue in the auto generated `Library` directory, this could be the case. Also, you may have an issue if you currently have the project open by another instance of Unity (ex: you're editing as `dondoo` but then `builduser` tries to make an automated build).

Hopefully my first answer fixes it, but if not there are a few things to check out!

--Patrick

Comment: The laptop only has the one user account, this is the same laptop I used to make a build of the project a week ago. The only thing that has changed has nothing to do with anything that could possibly break the project (i.e making ui appear or disappear) and I actually tried to bring in one of my many backups of the same projects and had the exact same issue so I figure the issue has to be with the machine or unity or Vuforia. I also just noticed the Library and Temp folder both say out of space under them even though the machine has plenty of space.

Comment: Did you try deleting Library and Temp? As long as Unity's not running at the time it should be safe (actually, temp should go away when you close Unity).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by deleting the library and Temp Folders the project came with and letting unity rebuild them.